# The below given is the response of the soap object how can i fetch the specific property from this response such as Message

Tags: android, xml, web-services

```
    anyType
    {schema=anyType
    {element=anyType
    {complexType=anyType
    {choice=anyType
    {element=anyType
    {complexType=anyType
    {sequence=anyType
    {element=anyType{}; 
    element=anyType{};
    element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; 
    diffgram=anyType
    {DocumentElement=anyType
{Login=anyType{Message=Success-95eb38fa-1bb4-4971-a7e0-d504690cda2e; AccountCount=17; LeadCount=11; 
}; }; }; }
```

I want to get the value of the property Message

Comment: you  want get this Message=Success-95eb38fa-1bb4-4971-a7e0-d504690cda2e one right?

Comment: i m getting {Login=anyType{Message=Success-95eb38fa-1bb4-4971-a7e0-d504690cda2e; AccountCount=17; LeadCount=11; 
}; }; }; } this as whole but how can i get Message=success

Comment: Try this: String result=((SoapObject) response).getProperty("message").toString();

Comment: no still its not working it is throwing exception but i have find a solution for that

Comment: post your exception and consuming code